# Code is working in ThisWorkbook but not in Personal.xlsb

Tags: vba, excel, macros

Both shift key on my laptop gets stuck a lot, I usually edit group sheets by accident in Excel when I navigate using ctrl+page up/down.

A friend made me a code which I can paste on ThisWorkbook in VBA however, I have tons of excel files.  The code he gave (below) would undo my group sheet edit and would deselect all except the other sheets. I'd like to know if there's a way this can work on Personal.xlsb so that I don't have to paste this code on all my files.

*(I'd like to thank in advanced, my internet connection is pretty weak here so I may not be able to respond immediately, but thanks for the help!)*

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
If ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Count > 1 Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim x As Integer
x = MsgBox("This will undo previous action taken. Do you want to continue?", vbYesNo, "Confirmation")
If x = vbYes Then
Application.Undo
Else
End If
ActiveSheet.Select
Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
If ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Count > 1 Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.Select
Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You can trap events at the application level - Google "Excel application events"

Comment: Saving you the trouble !   http://www.cpearson.com/excel/AppEvent.aspx

Comment: @TimWilliams learn something new every day.  Cool.

Comment: @TimWilliams - Thank you! I will study this :) I'm fascinated with how vba helps in Excel and I usually learn by following examples and experimenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a new Class module `clsAppEvents` in Personal.xlsb:

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set App = Application
End Sub

Private Sub App_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Debug.Print "Changed sheet '" & Sh.Name & "' in workbook '" & Sh.Parent.Name & "'"
    If ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Count > 1 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim x As Integer
        If MsgBox("This will undo previous action taken. Do you want to continue?", _
                                  vbYesNo, "Confirmation") = vbYes Then
            Application.Undo
        End If
        ActiveSheet.Select
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub App_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Debug.Print "Selection on sheet '" & Sh.Name & "' in workbook '" & Sh.Parent.Name & "'"
    If ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Count > 1 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        ActiveSheet.Select
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

In a regular code module:

```
Option Explicit

Dim oApp As clsAppEvents

Sub InitAppEvents()
    Set oApp = New clsAppEvents
End Sub
```

Alternatively you can put that in the `ThisWorkbook` code module, and link it to the `Workbook_Open` event.

Running `InitAppEvents` will start the capture of the events handled in the class module.

Note: anything which causes your VBA project to be reset (such as editing code or an unhandled error) will mean you'll need to reset the class instance capturing the events - i.e. re-run `InitAppEvents`.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Initially, I couldn't get it to work because I had not yet renamed the Class module.  My work revolves a lot around Excel so this will now save me a lot of times. I'm really grateful for this!